# Heroku python app crashes

Tags: python, heroku, flask

So I finally deployed my python app on heroku after so many trials and now, the app does not run. It returns an error in the logs with code "H10" and status 503.

My app.py is simply

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
return "Hello world"

if __name__ = '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

My requirements.txt

```
AppInst==2.1.5
Flask==0.12.2
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
Pillow==4.0.0
PyYAML==3.11
Pygments==2.1.3
Werkzeug==0.12.2
appdirs==1.4.3
apptools==4.4.0
argparse==1.4.0
attrs==15.2.0
backports-abc==0.5  
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0   
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.5.0
boto==2.40.0
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.3
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
colorthief==0.2.1
configobj==5.0.6
configparser==3.5.0
cycler==0.10.0  
decorator==4.0.9
dlib==19.4.0
docutils==0.13.1
ecdsa==0.13
encore==0.7.0
enstaller==4.8.12
entrypoints==0.2.2
enum34==1.1.6
envisage==4.6.0
esky==0.9.8
feedparser==5.2.1
flake8==3.3.0
futures==3.0.3
gnureadline==6.3.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
hatcher==0.10.4
html5lib==0.999
humanize==0.5.1
idna==2.5
imutils==0.4.3
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0 
ipywidgets==6.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.10.2
jsonify==0.5
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.0   
jupyter-console==5.1.0  
jupyter-core==4.3.0 
keyring==10.3.3
lxml==3.8.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
memory-profiler==0.43   
mistune==0.7.4
mpmath==0.19
nbconvert==5.2.1
nbformat==4.3.0
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.4.1
numpy==1.12.1
okonomiyaki==0.16.10
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.2.0.7
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.2
pandocfilters==1.4.1
path.py==10.3.1
pathlib2==2.2.1
pbr==3.0.1
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
pip==9.0.1
plotly==2.0.9
ply==3.10
prompt-toolkit==1.0.13  
psutil==5.2.2
psycopg2==2.7.1
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyface==5.1.0
pyflakes==1.5.0
pyglet==1.1.4
pymongo==3.4.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.3.0
requests==2.17.3
rsa==3.4.2
scipy==0.19.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.23.0
sympy==1.0
tabulate==0.7.7
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
traits==4.6.0
traits-enaml==0.2.1
traitsui==5.1.0
tzlocal==1.4
urllib3==1.21.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
cmake==0.7.1
```

My procfile

```
web: gunicorn malicha:app --log-file=-
```

Build pack

https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku14-buildpack-python-opencv-dlib.git

Comment: Okay. What is your Procfile ? And do you have requirements.txt file ?

Comment: What is `malicha` and that name is not matched with your app.py file. So I guess your `Procfile` will be `web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-`

Comment: Malicha is the name of the app

Comment: I guess you are not following Flask large project solution so I assume malicha is your project folder and inside all the app.py and Procfile in this case try my above solution.

Comment: Please how do l match the name of the app "malicha" with the app.py file

Comment: Come again I&#39;m not understand fully but I think you can rename the app.py to malicha.py and you don&#39;t have to change the Procfile at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and there are 2 things that helped me. As the comments have said your Procfile (the thing that helps your app start) has to match what you are actually trying to start.

So here is what yours might say: `web gunicorn main:app runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --log-file=-`

And here is what all that does, bit by bit:

The first word is the type of process you are asking for and in this case is "web." It may also say "worker" there but I assume you only have the one dyno and it is a free account which means this is what you want. You can always add complexity later.

Next to the green unicorn.

"gunicorn" is a more-efficient way to handle web requests. You could also have "python" there... but this is the recommended way.

Next is where you are having trouble. "main:app" or "malicha:app"... seems weird, right? Here is where that comes from.

Look inside your directory structure (your files, that is). If the thing you are trying to run is called

- main.py then you want main:app.

If the thing you are trying to run is called

- chatbot.py then you want chatbot:app.

The next one is obvious.

After that comes the port. You can grab this from inside your Flask app like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get port number from Heroku
    port = int(os.getenv("PORT"))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

But you do not need to change the Procfile beyond what I have written.

Finally the logs. Also obvious.

*You also don't need all those in the Requirements.txt but that is a venv issue and we can save that for another day.*

Hope that helps.